# How do I create a data frame that keeps the original columns but performs a function on one of them?

Tags: r

I am trying to round up the decimal points in the "avg_price" column in this dataset

```
structure(list(designer_name = c("A Quaint Stitch", "AllSewPetite", 
"American Stitchers", "Amy Butler"), avg_price = c(7.11818181818182, 
2.785, 11.4736842105263, 11.0454545454545)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want group_by_dn to show the designer_name column and the avg_price column rounded up to the next integer.

when I do a function on one of the columns, it gives me the output

```
ceiling(as.integer(group_by_dn$avg_price))
```

```
 [1]  7  2 11 11  5  7  9  5 10 11  7  6 11 12  8  7  8  9  9  8  9 12  8  9  7  9
 [27] 12  5 10  6  8  6  5  9  9 16  8  3  7 14  9  4  9  7  8  6 10  8  7  8  5  9
 [53]  6  6  5  7 19 10  7  8  8  3  8  8  9  7  9  8  8  8 15  9 12 12  8  4 17  8
 [79] 14  4 10  0  3  7  8  1  6 10  7  7  6  5  9  7  8 15  7 10  9  7  4  8  8 15
[105]  7  7  0 11  7  5  6  7  6 11  6  9  0 10  6 15  0  8  9  7  5  9 25  6 NA  8
[131]  8 12  6  3 10 12 NA NA 13  9  8  8  9  7 NA  7 11  8  6  8  8
```

but it doesn't make the change in the data frame.

I know there's a simple answer but my Google Fu is failing me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this. However, it seems like you might not be aware that there is almost no mutability in R.

```
df1$avg_price <- as.integer(ceiling(df1$avg_price))
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   designer_name      avg_price
#   <chr>                  <int>
# 1 A Quaint Stitch            8
# 2 AllSewPetite               3
# 3 American Stitchers        12
# 4 Amy Butler                12
```

Using the `tidyverse` library:

```
df1 <- mutate(df1, new_avg = ceiling(avg_price),
              ano_avg = as.integer(avg_price))
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   designer_name      avg_price new_avg ano_avg
#   <chr>                  <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
# 1 A Quaint Stitch         7.12       8       7
# 2 AllSewPetite            2.78       3       2
# 3 American Stitchers     11.5       12      11
# 4 Amy Butler             11.0       12      11
```

Comment: Thanks! I am brand new to R coding so unfortunately I don't know what mutability means?

Comment: Well, first, I've used the term incorrectly (sorry, go me). The correct def of mutability is whether or not you can mutate an object after it's created. In Python, you can't mutate a `set`. You can replace it with one with the same name. What I meant when I said mutability was about the assignment operator (in R that's = or <-) In many languages, you don't need to explicitly document the `=`. For example, in C languages, you can create an object like this `char buf[50]` in Python, you can modify a list with this `lst.sort()`. In R, you almost always need the `=` or `<-`.